# Can't find bundle for base name

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using a library that has a dependency on jfreechart (v 1.0.9).

When I try to run the .jar, I get:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name
        org.jfree.chart.LocalizationBundle, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException
        (ResourceBundle.java:1521)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1260)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:962)
```

I've tried creating a LocalizationBundle.properties file, but that didnt do it. I've checked the CLASSPATH, still no go.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> ```
> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name
>     org.jfree.chart.LocalizationBundle, locale en_US
> ```

To the point, the exception message tells in detail that you need to have either of the following files in the classpath:

```
/org/jfree/chart/LocalizationBundle.properties
```

or

```
/org/jfree/chart/LocalizationBundle_en.properties
```

or

```
/org/jfree/chart/LocalizationBundle_en_US.properties
```

Also see [the official Java tutorial about resourcebundles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html) for more information.

But as this is actually a 3rd party managed properties file, you shouldn't create one yourself. It should be already available in the JFreeChart JAR file. So ensure that you have it available in the classpath during runtime. Also ensure that you're using the right version, the location of the propertiesfile inside the package tree *might* have changed per JFreeChart version.

When executing a JAR file, you can use the `-cp` argument to specify the classpath. E.g.:

```
java -jar -cp c:/path/to/jfreechart.jar yourfile.jar
```

Alternatively you can specify the classpath as `class-path` entry in the JAR's manifest file. You can use in there relative paths which are relative to the JAR file itself. Do **not** use the `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable, it's **ignored** by JAR's and everything else which aren't executed with `java.exe` *without* `-cp`, `-classpath` and `-jar` arguments.

Comment: It is also worth checking that you don't have typos in your bundle name, I spend 30 min debugging my app just to realize that when I renamed my bundle from IDE I accidentally added a space in front of it (I worked on Linux box so OS doesn't complain). Facepalm...

Answer (score 4):

If you are using IntelliJ IDE just right click on resources package and go to new and then select Resource Boundle it automatically create a .properties file for you. This did work for me .

Answer (score 2):

BalusC is right. Version 1.0.13 is current, but 1.0.9 appears to have the required bundles:

```
$ jar tf lib/jfreechart-1.0.9.jar | grep LocalizationBundle.properties 
org/jfree/chart/LocalizationBundle.properties
org/jfree/chart/editor/LocalizationBundle.properties
org/jfree/chart/plot/LocalizationBundle.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the .properties file under src/ folder at the same level as com solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot project - needed to add "org.jfree.chart.LocalizationBundle" dir structure manually (each dir and subdir) inside resources dir, otherwise didn't work for me.