# Java unit test can't access ResourceBundle

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock, resourcebundle

I am creating a Java unit test to test some code I recently changed. However, the method I am testing instantiates a class which uses ResourceBundle …

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("businessVariables").getString("product.name"));
```

The resource file lives in the web package at `Mycompany_web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/businessVariables.properties`

My test lives in my xml package at `Mycompany_xml/src/test/java/uk/co/mycompany/xmlapi/RequestProcessorTestNew.java`

During normal runtime the resource bundle is accessible, but not when my unit test is run. It throws this error …

```
Testcase: testCreateInitialStatusResponse(uk.co.mycompany.xmlapi.RequestProcessorTestNew):  Caused an ERROR
null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at uk.co.mycompany.xmlapi.RequestProcessorTestNew.testCreateInitialStatusResponse(RequestProcessorTestNew.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at uk.co.mycompany.xmlapi.RequestProcessorImpl.createInitialStatusResponse(RequestProcessorImpl.java:812)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name businessVariables, locale en_US
```

What should I do? Can I enable my test to see the resource bundle somehow? Can I create a mock resource file somewhere which somehow the code will be able to see?

Comment: Have you tried renaming the bundle to suite the `en_Us` locale? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083159/cant-find-bundle-for-base-name

Comment: Anyway, following Kaylan's answer, `/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` seems like a the *target* folder. Look into your project structure - the bundle file would better be in e.g. `Mycompany_web/src/main/resources/businessVariables.properties`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have build your project structure according to Maven archetype, your resource bundle should ideally be in Mycompany_xml/src/test/resources. Then you can run unit tests from project home i.e. Mycompany_xml directory using mvn test.

While packaging the war, copy the resource bundle from Mycompany_xml/src/test/resources to the war using maven-assembly-plugin.

Comment: This is correct. However, also note that the pom file can define an alternative place to put the resources file.e.g             <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${basedir}/conf</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>