# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name Bundle

Tags: java, eclipse

I am encountering an issue when trying to load a resource.

```
java.util.ResourceBundle bundle = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle");
```

My file is correctly named `Bundle_en_US.properties` in the `src` folder.

While I am aware of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083159/cant-find-bundle-for-base-name#2083186) (and [many others](https://www.google.com/search?q=java.util.MissingResourceException:+Can%27t+find+bundle+for+base+name+Bundle+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNkrTBrrjcAhWEGDQIHX9DCDUQrQIIQSgEMAE)), **my case is different because my Java program runs fine from Eclipse but the error below is triggered when ran from an executable jar file.**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name Bundle, locale en_US

                at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)

                at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)

                at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
```

I am using: Windows 10, Eclipse Photon, JDK 8 and JDK 10, JRE 8 and JRE 10

And I can see all my *.properties files in the jar file when opening with an archive manager :
[image]

Comment: You've manually checked that it's there in the .jar file?

Comment: Good question but yes, I've opened the jar file with 7Zip and I can see the *.properties files under src

Comment: Your .jar file has a "src" folder? That doesn't sound right. At the least it's not part of the bundle name you're passing in.

Comment: No, I don't pass the src in the bundle name (see my code in my question). But my jar has an src folder right at the root at the jar, is that not correct ?

Comment: Are the properties files in the root folder of the jar?

Comment: Like I mentioned i my question, they're in the src folder

Comment: What are the full paths of the class file and properties file when they're in the jar? You might want to debug and step through the loading in Eclipse so you understand where it's expecting the properties file to be.

Comment: Sure, I could debug and I might but since it's working when launching from Eclipse, it will be hard to see a potential clue as it will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution to my own issue. The reason was that in the `.classpath` file, only the .java files were outputted. Hence, my properties files were outputted in a different directory and were not found by the resourceLoader.

Original .classpath entry :

```
<classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src">
```

Resolved by modifying the line entry to :

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src">
```